# Android progress bar is null

Tags: android, android-fragments, progress-bar

I am having a little strange problem. I have a **ProgressBar** in my layout file. **onPreExecute** I show the progress bar and **onPostExecute** I hide the progress bar. But In **onPreExecute** method            `ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);` progressBar is always ***null*** where as same line of code works fine in **onPostExecute**.

***Async Task in MainActivity***

```
@Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }


@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            mainList.setAdapter(sectionAdapter);
            sectionAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            mainList.setOnItemClickListener(new mainListClicked());

        }
```

***progressBar is in fragment_mainview.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >    
     <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />  
</RelativeLayout>
```

For more information I am populating **activity_main.xml** layout by **fragment_main.xml** using fragments as following.

```
@Override


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                  FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = 
                  fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                  MainViewFragment mianFragment = new MainViewFragment();
                  fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, mianFragment);
                  fragmentTransaction.commit();

            mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
            mainList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mainListView);
            mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

              new LoadListInBackground().execute();
    }
```

And **activity_main.xml** is as following

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

     <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >



        <ListView 
            android:id="@+id/mainListView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            />

    </FrameLayout>

    <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:background="#FFF"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: when and where you are calling the AsycTask.execute ?

Comment: Hi. @RajeshCP . I have edited the question.
First I am populating main view by fragment.
After that I am executing background task which takes up to 5-7 seconds to complete .

Comment: new LoadListInBackground().execute(); you write this code inside your fragment

Comment: then my solution was incorrect, sorry. Yes i'm trying to understand more from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html  and Processes and Threads : http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html

Comment: LoadListInBackground is inner class of MainActivity and I am inflating fragment in a separate class

Comment: Are you sure the Null is at findviewbyId..maybe the reference for async task in the fragment in separate class is weak, are you getting null at ".setVisibility" or return point from onPre.. ?

Comment: Yes, Null is at findviewbyId. Now I will try to inflate fragment in an inner class and will post results here